# Apache FOP: Displaying UTF-8 Characters in PDF (without embed?)

Tags: apache, pdf, utf-8, fonts, apache-fop

I'm trying to use FOP to export a PDF with UTF-8 characters, preferably without needing to embed the font.
The following code:

```
<fo:block font="10pt Helvetica" text-align="justify" space-after="10pt" space-before="8pt" keep-with-previous="auto" keep-together.within-page="auto"> 
  <fo:block font-weight="bold" color="gray">Summary</fo:block>
  <fo:block text-indent="1em" keep-with-previous="always">
    <fo:block text-indent="1em" space-before="4pt">
      <fo:block text-indent="1em" space-before="4pt">私はガラスを食べられます。それは私を傷つけません
      </fo:block>
    </fo:block>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

produces #################### in the PDF.  I'm aware of the issue: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#pdf-characters

When I go under Document Properties->Fonts, the Helvetica font is listed with 'Encoding: ANSI'.  Is there a way to change this?

If I were embedding, what would be the best way to do so without having access to Helvetica.ttf?  I've tried using DejaVuSans, but I end up with squares in place of the # signs.

Note that this is not a one-time use from the command line (that would be a start), but an extension to an existing app.  I'm trying to support UTF-8 characters without too much complexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAICT, the fonts included in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) only include characters from ISO-Latin-1.  If you want a character that falls outside of those defined in *Annex D: Character Sets and Encodings*, then you are expected to embed the font.